# inflating class fragment in google maps v2 on real android device 2.3?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I dont't know what will i do to make my app run normally in real device

i work google maps v1 in my app from 2 year ago, but from google docs say "v1 is deprecated" and i knew yesterday. i want to change my app to google maps v2 and I got problem, in log show

```
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidmapsv2/com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     ... 11 more
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at maps.e.ch.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at maps.e.bg.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at maps.e.bf.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at eio.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
03-19 15:07:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(9540):     ... 20 more
```

i know in this forum much same question like this, but all answer cant solve the problem, I've tried tutorial from any link and from google docs but never succes,, I think my problem in my phone, i use android 2.3.6 gingerbread (real device).

this mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    private GoogleMap myMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
            = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
         myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_legalnotices:
            String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
                    getApplicationContext());
            AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
            LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
            LicenseDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
        }

    }

}
```

**manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidmapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBD9fsiMd_G9Pzeq2Eqas2FwJjzMGbSOnA"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

maybe anybody ever got same problem with me? how you solve the problem?

thanks

Comment: post the full stacktrace the manifest file the layout file and the activity class

Comment: question has been edited.

Comment: also the full stacktrace not just 1 line

Comment: add this as a child of applciation tag `<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Comment: my question has been edited again

Comment: i already answered before you posted the stacktrace. pls check my previous comment

Comment: where i place <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />  ? in above tag <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBD9fsiMd_G9Pzeq2Eqas2FwJjzMGbSOnA"/> or another location? sorry im new bie..

Comment: inside the application tag of manifest

Comment: i placed that meta-data inside application tag but i get diferent result error, i will copy the log and i put in question.

Comment: stacktrace has been change in my question after i add meta-data inside application tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the
>   additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml
>   to ensure a correct behavior: 03-19 15:07:30.429:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9540):

Add this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Could add the above where you have other permissions defined

I already suggested adding the below as a child of application tag

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest, put this at the end of the application definition, just before the aplication closing:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBD9fsiMd_G9Pzeq2Eqas2FwJjzMGbSOnA"/>
```

And just before this, put also this:

```
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

With this all, if you have done all the creating API key and all this stuff correctly, you should have this woirking

Comment: @Raghunandan do you refer to the call in the xml file?

Comment: what reference are you talking about?

Comment: @Raghunandan you told me that there is no need for MapFragment. I don't understand what do you refer to

Comment: i Use android device 2.3 and as i know fragment in device using supportMapFragment

Comment: i said no need for this `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` SupportMapFragment is fine and what you suggested is wrogn  coz min sdk is 8